# Proof $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}$ $[a_n,b_n]$ $\neq \emptyset$ with given conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help for the following task:

a)Formulate the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:
Each bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R^n}$ has a convergent subsequence.

b) Let {$a_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence that is monotonically increasing and {$b_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence that is monotonically decreasing. Both are sequences of real numbers with the property $a_n$$\leq b_n$ $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that:

$i)$ $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}$ $[a_n,b_n]$ $\neq \emptyset$

The only approach I have is:
Since {$a_n$} is monotonically increasing we have $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$. And for {$b_n$} we have $b_{n+1}\leq b_n$. Since {$a_n$}$\leq${$b_n$}, are we allowed to say, that {$a_n$} is bounded? Then if yes, we could use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. But in which way? How can I reach: [$a_1,b_1$]$\cap $[$a_2,b_2$]...$\cap$[$a_n,b_n$]=$\emptyset$

$i)$ If we have additionally, that $b_n - a_n$ $\rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow 0$, then $x \in \mathbb{R}$ exists with

$\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}$ $[a_n,b_n]$ = {x}

Well here we have the addition, that {$b_n - a_n$} is a convergent sequence, right? But thats all I have unfortunately...

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Show that $sup\{a_n: n \geq 1\}$ belongs to $[a_n,b_n]$ for all $n$.

Comment: You can see that $a_1\leq a_n\leq b_n\leq b_1$ for all $n$ since $a_n$ is increasing and $b_n$ is decreasing. This shows that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both bounded

Comment: To take care of both parts show that the intersection equals the closed interval $[\sup a_n, \inf b_n]$.